# CSS inline element causing different margins

Tags: css

I'm facing this problem. The CSS code is 100% same. No interference from any other code.

**Code:**

```
.items a {
font-size: 12px;
text-transform: lowercase;
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
line-height: 1;
padding: 3px 5px;
border-radius: 25px;
color: #C0BEBE;
}


<div class="items">
<a href="http://example.com/tag/art-design/">Art &amp; Design</a>
<a href="http://example.com/tag/bamboo/">bamboo</a>
<a href="http://example.com/tag/fancy/">fancy</a>
<a href="http://example.com/tag/tags/">tags</a>
<a href="http://example.com/tag/waqas/">waqas</a>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: and your HTML code please

Comment: just tried to build a Demo on the basis of your code. let me know if it work for you. http://jsbin.com/notilife/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out.

I set line-height of container (.items in my case) to 1 and now the result is looking same at both pages.

```
.items {line-height: 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try to add `margin` to you rules, to make it persistent. Now it uses browser defined style. And, yes, can you, please give your html and on what browsers you are checking.

Or, you can use some reset.css like for example this one: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just tried to build a full Demo without further information. Let me know if its work for you.

Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/notilife/1/edit)**.

**CSS Code**

```
ul{margin:0; padding:0; width:240px;text-align:center;}
li{list-style-type:none; padding:4px;display: inline-block;
 }

.items a {
font-size: 16px;
text-transform: lowercase;
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
line-height: 1;
padding: 3px 5px;
border-radius: 15px;
color: #C0BEBE;

  text-decoration:none;
  min-width:30px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<ul>
    <li class="items"><a href="#">Art & Design</a></li>
    <li class="items"><a href="#">Bamboo</a></li>
    <li class="items"><a href="#">Fancy</a></li>
    <li class="items"><a href="#">Tag</a></li>
    <li class="items"><a href="#">Waqas</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Sorry didn't mention my html before. I'm using div. Why use list when we can do without. Minimal is better.

Answer (score 0):

Write the code at the top of your css file , to remove browsers default behavior !

```
  *{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  }
```

: [or You can use reset css file](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/)